# Hopf bifurcation in linear delay differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, delay-differential-equations

Can equilibria of a system of linear delay differential equations undergo a Hopf bifurcation? I am able to generate oscillatory solutions by tuning a time delay in the system, but would it make sense to argue that such oscillations result from the loss of stability of equilibria? The system is linear, just to be clear.